# JVM Getting -Xmx512m when I give it 1024m

Tags: java, gradle

I'm trying to run a gradle program and when I provide the following command the JVM still reports "-Xmx512m" for some reason (Using VirtualJVM to view). Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

I notice when I configure the XMX command here, it configures it for the Wrapper not the subsequent Worker that runs the tests, that is where I need the memory increase.

```
C:\Users\ATA058\Desktop\GitRepos\gems-root\gems-core-domain>"C:\Program Files\Eclipse Foundation\jdk-11.0.12.7-hotspot\/bin/java.exe" -Xmx1024m -noverify "-Dorg.gradle.appname=gradlew" -classpath "C:\Users\ATA
058\Desktop\GitRepos\gems-root\gems-core-domain\\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.jar" org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain clean test
```

[image]

Comment: VisuamVM seems to show a different process that what you've started, maybe a child process. Note you running `GradleWrapperMain` while VisualVM shows `GradleWorkerMain`.

Comment: You seem to be running tests...  You configure heap for tests in the gradle build script itself... see https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.html

Comment: @Thomas Yes, it's because I stopped the process before taking the screenshot. The worker is the correct process.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GradleWorkerMain OutOfMemoryError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20490105/gradleworkermain-outofmemoryerror)